# How to tell a colleague in email to stop harping on your mistake?

Tags: email

What is a good way to write to tell your colleague to move on from past mistakes and focus on the bigger issue on hand?

Comment: Perhaps make it seem like a suggestion, but a reasonable one: "It probably makes sense to move on from the mistake in my calculations, though, to focus on the bigger picture." Just be civil and clear, and not pushy or defensive. (Though I may be wrong, I don't think this question is going to get much traction here, however, as it lacks a specific English usage question. There are probably hundreds of answers to it.)

Comment: @ancelot  well, I have a question here, Though I understand the reason why you would not want to belittle your status but why would it be wrong to 'sound personal'? I don't see anything wrong with it. Is it unprofessional to do that if it's just your colleague? or is it simply your choice?

Comment: If only work groups comprised only reasonable people, then Cargill's excellent letter below would do the trick.  But they aren't, and it probably won't.  There's every probability that Steve will hear the final line as "I'm sure you'll agree that we need to keep our focus on the main goals and not the trivial nit-picking and petty one-upmanship that you and your team constantly employ to sabotage the project."  Email is devoid of tone of voice, body language, and real-time reciprocal response.  Avoid it for situtations like this.  Talk to Steve face to face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve,

I refer to the miscalculation in respect of the cash-flow analysis on the new Milan Project. We appreciate the work you and your team did to help identify these very subtle errors, and for our part, the finance team has worked hard to make the necessary corrections.

We are now confident that the project timeline is completely back on track, and the client group is very satisfied with progress to date. I trust that you and your team now share our confidence, and while the error has been acknowledged and addressed, it need not delay or distract us any further.

I'm sure you'll agree that we need to look firmly forward and keep our perspective focused on the main goals of the Milan Project.

Regards, Phil